# RSpec gives me a routing error when trying to test update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test the update functionality on my `genres_controller` and though it works just fine when I run the app, RSpec returns me an `UrlGenerationError`. I tried many alternatives but none of them work. Here's the code:

**genres_spec**

```rb
describe "PUT genre" do
    it "should update genre" do
      request.headers["Authorization"] = "Token token=#{@token}"
      old_genre = Genre.find(1)
      patch api_v1_genre_path(1) #I tried replacing this with just 'patch :update' with params but it does not work.
      puts response.body
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do

      # Basic routes
      resources :users
      resources :studios
      resources :genres
      resources :productions
      resources :characters

      #Auth routes
      post "auth", to: "auth#create", as: "auth"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you include the *exact* error text?

Comment: Hardcoding IDs into your specs (or anywhere else) is never a good idea  and you should not have to find the record from the database as you should have just created it. You are cleaning the database properly between specs aren't you?
Use `let(:genre){ FactoryBot.create(:genre) }` or if you're using fixtures `let(:genre){ genres[:one] }`.

Comment: Also `patch :update` only works in  controller specs where you're creating an instance of the controller and calling the method on it. The use of controller specs is extemly discouraged by both the RSpec and Rails teams - do not use them. Use request, feature or system specs.